# iam getting error in this sqlite query combining where and order by clauses

Tags: android, sqlite

```
  mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DataBase.TABLE_NAME +  " ORDER BY "      +KEY_EVENTDATE+
                    " WHERE " + KEY_YEAR + " = ? AND " + KEY_MONTH + " = ?", new String[]{cy, month[j]} );
```

what is wrong with query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql syntax is wrong. Order by should come after where condition.

Here is the corrected query.

```
mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DataBase.TABLE_NAME 
 + " WHERE " + KEY_YEAR + " = ? AND " + KEY_MONTH + " = ?" 
 +  " ORDER BY " +KEY_EVENTDATE, new String[]{cy, month[j]} );
```

Comment: thank u...query is working now...excellent and quick response